# Renewed Apple developer account with wrong credit card

Tags: developer-program, apple-store

I paid my Apple developer account membership (renew) order with my brothers credit card. What to do? Can I cancel this order and renew again with my credit card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any issue if the payment has made though and your account is renewed. You can simply pay back your brother :)

In theory you should be able to contact Apple Developer support and ask for a cancellation, but since you said you wish to renew anyways, I don't think it is necessary. If you are concerned that your card may get charged by Apple Developer for some developer service, be assured that there's no other charges associated with Apple Developer Program membership, that may get billed on your card without your consent.

Next year, when renewing, you can use your card again. Please note not to use your brother's card again without thinking twice!

It is possible to change the payment method associated with your Apple ID anytime.